# what's wrong with my tensorflow code

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I just begin to study tensorflow and I want to create a DNN for MNIST. In the tutorial, there is a very simple neural network with 784 input nodes, 10 output nodes and no hidden nodes. I try to modify these codes to create a DNN network. Here is my code. I think I just add a hidden layer with 500 nodes between input and output layers, but the test accuracy is just 10%, which means it is not trained. Do you know what's wrong with my codes?

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

import os
os.chdir('../')

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)

x=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,784])
W_h1=tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784,500]))
B_h1=tf.Variable(tf.zeros([500]))
h1=tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(x,W_h1)+B_h1)
'''
W_h2=tf.Variable(tf.zeros([5,5]))
B_h2=tf.Variable(tf.zeros([5]))
h2=tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h1,W_h2)+B_h2)
'''
B_o=tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
W_o=tf.Variable(tf.zeros([500,10]))
y=tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h1,W_o)+B_o)

y_=tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y), reduction_indices=[1]))

train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.05).minimize(cross_entropy)
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

number_steps = 10000
batch_size = 100
for _ in range(number_steps):
  batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
  train=sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

  # Print classifier's accuracy
print(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels}))
```

OK, according to @lejlot's suggestion, I change my code as following.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

import os
os.chdir('../')

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)

x=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,784])
W_h1=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([784,500]))
B_h1=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([500]))
h1=tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(x,W_h1)+B_h1)
'''
W_h2=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([500,500]))
B_h2=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([500]))
h2=tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h1,W_h2)+B_h2)
'''
B_o=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([10]))
W_o=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([500,10]))
y= tf.matmul(h1,W_o)+B_o # notice no activation

y_=tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.nn.log_softmax(y), # notice log_softmax
                  reduction_indices=[1]))

train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

number_steps = 10000
batch_size = 100
for i in range(number_steps):
  batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
  train=sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})
  if i % 1000==0:
    acc=sess.run(accuracy,feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels})
    print('Current loop %d, Accuracy: %g'%(i,acc))



  # Print classifier's accuracy
print(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels}))
```

There are two modification:

1. change the initial value of W_h1 and B_h1 with tf.random_normal
2. change the define of y and cross_entropy

The modification dose work. But I still don't know what's wrong with my original code. I call the tf.global_variables_initializer().run(), and I think this function will random the value of W_h1 and B_h1. Besides, if I define y and cross_entropy as following, it doesn't work.

```
y= tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(h1,W_o)+B_o) 
y_=tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y),reduction_indices=[1]))
```

Comment: What if you reduce the learning rate to 0.002 and increase the number of steps? 0.05 is a very high learning rate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all this is not valid classifier model.

```
y=tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h1,W_o)+B_o)

y_=tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y), reduction_indices=[1]))
```

You are using explicit equation for cross entropy which requires `y` to be a (row-wise) probability distribution, yet you produce `y` by applying relu, meaning that you are simply outputing some non-negative numbers. In fact, if you ever output zeros, your code will produce NaNs and fail (as log of 0 is minus infinity).

You should use

```
y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(h1,W_o)+B_o)
```

instead. Or even better (for better numerical stability):

```
y= tf.matmul(h1,W_o)+B_o # notice no activation

y_=tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(
                  -tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.nn.log_softmax(y), # notice log_softmax
                  reduction_indices=[1]))
```

## update

Second issue is initialisation - you **cannot** initialise neural network weights to **zeros**, they have to be random numbers, typically sampled from low-variance zero-mean Gaussians. Global initialiser **does not** randomise weights, it simply runs all the initialisation ops - if the initialisation ops are constant ones (like zeros), it simply makes sure these zeros are assigned to variables, nothing else (thus it can be used to reset the network etc.). Zero initialisation works only for convex problems, such as logistic regression, but cannot work for complex model like neural network.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but it does not have change.

Comment: There is at least one more problem (addressed in the answer know). Once you fix it- please update the code in the question, reduce the learning rate, and it should work

Comment: when I random the initial weights and change the cross_entropy, it does work. But I thought I called tf.global_variables_initializer().run() to random the weights, and in the tutorial, it uses zero initialization and this function to initialise variables.

Comment: no, global initialiser just runs operations that you defined, so if they are contant they will stay constant. Zero initialisation works only for linear models, so I guess tutorial was using logistic regression?

Comment: Yeah, I know the problem. The initializer only execute the assignment statements of variables, not random them. The tuitorial uses the softmax and no hidden units. Thanks very much. And there is another question. When I define the cross_entropy with log_softmax, it works well. But if I define it seperately, which means I define the y with softmax first and define corss_entropy with y_*tf.log(y), it doesn't work. So what's the matter with the last definition?

Comment: Yes, the cross_entropy is nan and the test accuracy is 0.098 after training.

Comment: It is because log(softmax()) is not numericaly stable (softmax is not safe for big input signals), log_softmax() is

Comment: Yes, and I think I often get the vanished gradient

Comment: no, vanishing gradient has nothing to do with nans.